# Node JS uploading file field as a field of an object in the request body using Formidable

Tags: node.js, typescript, formidable

I am building a Node JS application using Express JS. I need to implement the file upload logic for my application. I am using Formidable, https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable for uploading file(s). I could upload the files using that library without any issue when the request body format is simple. Now, I am trying to upload the file which is a property/ field of an object in the request body. The following is the dummy request body structure.

```
{
  users: [
     {
       name: `Test User 1`,
       photoFile: {{ here I want to upload file for this user }}
     },
     {
       name: `Test User 2`,
       photoFile: {{ here I want to upload file for this user }}
     },
     // the list goes on
  ]
}
```

I am trying to send the test payload/ data in the Postman as in the screenshot below.

[image]

This is my code to parse the form

```
private getForm = async (
    req: Request,
    options: FormOptions = {
      multiples: false
    }
  ) => {
    const tempUploadDir = this.getTempUploadDirectory(req);
    if (!(await this.storage.exits(tempUploadDir))) {
      await this.storage.mkdir(tempUploadDir);
    }

    return new IncomingForm({
      multiples: options.multiples,
      uploadDir: tempUploadDir,
      maxFileSize: config.fileSystem.maxUploadLimit
    });
  };

  public parseFormData = async <T>(
    request: Request,
    options: FormOptions = {
      multiples: false
    }
  ): Promise<T> => {
    const form = await this.getForm(request, options);
    return new Promise<T>((resolve) => {
      form.parse(request, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) {
          if (err.code === FILE_TOO_LARGE_ERROR_CODE) {
            // file too large
            throw new UploadMaxFileSizeException(
              `Upload file size limit exceeded.`
            );
          }
          throw err;
        }

        let filesData: {
          [key: string]: IUploadedFile[];
        } = {};
        for (let fileField in files) {
          if (`length` in files[fileField]) {
            filesData[fileField] = files[fileField] as IUploadedFile[];
          } else {
            filesData[fileField] = [files[fileField] as IUploadedFile];
          }
        }

        return resolve({
          ...fields,
          ...files
        } as T);
      });
    });
  };
```

When I print out the result of parseFormData, I am getting the following result.

[image]

As you can see, the field field, 'users[0][photoFile]' is not parsed putting into the corresponding field of the request body object. Instead, the entire field name is string, 'users[0][photoFile]'. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I my project, file will upload to server when user upload files and get the link back

And when submit form, user avatar just is a link, not a file

Comment: The issue I am having is parsing the fields of the payload into the right format.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).